# Why liquibase thru docker-compose keeps throwing: changelog.yaml: No such file or directory?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, liquibase

I'm trying to implement liquibase in my Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: data-service:dev
    container_name: data-service
    environment:
      - MONGO_DB=mongodb://user:pass@mongodatab/careers
      - POSTGRES_DB=jdbc:postgresql://postgresdatab
    ports:
      - '8090:8090'
    command: '/bin/bash -c "sleep 5; mongosh $$MONGO_DB --eval \"show dbs;\""'
    depends_on:
      - mongodatab
      - liquibasePostgres

  mongodatab:
    image: mongodb/mongodb-community-server:6.0-ubi8
    container_name: data-service-mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./../db
        target: /db/mongodb

  postgresdatab:
    image: postgres
    container_name: data-service-postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  liquibasePostgres:
    image: liquibase/liquibase:latest
    container_name: data-service-liquibasePostgres
    depends_on:
      - postgresdatab
    command: --url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresdatab:5432/postgres?user=postgres&password=postgres --changeLogFile=/liquibase/changelog/changelog.yaml update
    volumes:
      - ./liquibase/postgres/changelog.yaml:/liquibase/changelog/changelog.yaml

volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

then the liquibasePostgres service throws error:

```
Starting Liquibase at 05:36:13 (version 4.23.2 #13458 built at 2023-09-11 22:00+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.23.2
[2023-09-13 05:36:13] INFO [liquibase.ui] Liquibase Version: 4.23.2
[2023-09-13 05:36:13] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.licenseKey found
[2023-09-13 05:36:13] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.pro.licenseKey found
Liquibase Open Source 4.23.2 by Liquibase
[2023-09-13 05:36:13] INFO [liquibase.ui] Liquibase Open Source 4.23.2 by Liquibase
[2023-09-13 05:36:13] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.monitorPerformance found
[2023-09-13 05:36:13] FINE [liquibase.configuration] Configuration liquibase.monitorPerformance is using the default value of false
[2023-09-13 05:36:13] FINE [liquibase.integration] Performance monitoring disabled
[2023-09-13 05:36:13] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.logging.mdc.MdcManager instance liquibase.logging.mdc.NoOpMdcManager
[2023-09-13 05:36:13] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.logging.mdc.MdcManager instance com.datical.liquibase.ext.logging.structured.StructuredMdcManager
[2023-09-13 05:36:13] INFO [liquibase.integration] Starting command execution.
**Missing required subcommand**
Usage: liquibase [GLOBAL OPTIONS] [COMMAND] [COMMAND OPTIONS]
Command-specific help: "liquibase <command-name> --help"
```

If I run a container in -it mode independently with:

```
docker run --net="host" -v ./liquibase/postgres/changelog.yaml:/liquibase/changelog/changelog.yaml -it --entrypoint /bin/bash liquibase/liquibase -s
```

in order to inspect, I manage to get inside the liquibase container:

```
liquibase@docker-desktop:/liquibase$ pwd
/liquibase
liquibase@docker-desktop:/liquibase$ ls
ABOUT.txt  changelog      classpath             examples             internal  licenses     liquibase      liquibase.docker.properties  README.txt
bin        changelog.txt  docker-entrypoint.sh  GETTING_STARTED.txt  lib       LICENSE.txt  liquibase.bat  liquibase-env.sh             UNINSTALL.txt
liquibase@docker-desktop:/liquibase$ ls changelog
**changelog.yaml**
liquibase@docker-desktop:/liquibase$
```

So the changelog is copied and then I just execute liquibase shell manually to emulate the comand and changeSet execution:

```
liquibase --log-level=debug --url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresdatab/postgres?user=postgres&password=postgres --changeLogFile=/changelog/changelog.yaml update
```

that throws error:

```
[1] 11
bash: --changeLogFile=/changelog/changelog.yaml: No such file or directory
liquibase@docker-desktop:/liquibase$ ####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ## 
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ## 
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 05:47:39 (version 4.23.2 #13458 built at 2023-09-11 22:00+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.23.2
Liquibase Open Source 4.23.2 by Liquibase
Missing required subcommand
Usage: liquibase [GLOBAL OPTIONS] [COMMAND] [COMMAND OPTIONS]
Command-specific help: "liquibase <command-name> --help"
```

I have tried updating the path to:
`./changelog/changelog.yaml`
`changelog.yaml`
`/liquibase/changelog/changelog.yaml`
etc, etc but keeps NOT finding it apparently, any idea why?